# Brewing with rice. Rice cooker vs Cereal Mash?

Tags: brewing, adjuncts

Instead of performing a cereal mash which can be done as so:

1. Mill rice
2. Mix 10-15% malted barley to provide a fluid mash
3. Raise temp to 158F for 30 minutes
4. Boil for 15-20 minutes
5. Add to main mash

Can I instead?

1. Cook rice as normal in rice cooker
2. Add to main mash

It seems to me that both steps are processes are basically the same. The rice will be gelatinized in either method because boiling is involved. In a cereal mash one of the differences is that malted barley is added to the very finely ground rice so you don't produce a very thick easily burned pudding.

I guess I might see less efficiency using a rice cooker since I haven't ground up my rice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose will work.  You can also use Minute Rice, in which case you can just toss it on the mash and not have to precook the rice either way.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a rice porridge in the rice cooker that will make the rice into a thick paste (with some very soft grains still floating around). Add extra water to the rice cooker (maybe double the usual amount?), let it boil for a few minutes and then turn down the power (the rice cooker would try to boil all the liquid away if you let it). Then wait a while until you have the consistency you want, add water if needed.